# Aggregate Kafka processed data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer that performs some migrations. Pretty simple flow

```
@KafkaListener(topics="client-migration-blah", groupId="migration-group",
          containerFactory="kafkaListnerContainerFactory")
public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, Object> payload) {
   try {
    Client client = payload.value();
    if( migrationClient.clientExists(client)) {
            updateClient(ClientEvent.UPDATE, client);
    }
    else {
          migrationClient.importClient(ClientEvent.CREATE, client);
      }
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      log.error("yada yada yada");
       sendToDLQ(ClientEvent.ERROR, client);
      }
  }
```

I need a breakup of the three usecases, create, update and error(DLQ). Short of building a streaming (?) solution to collect these aggregates, what would be a simple way to gather these events to extract the breakup?

Comment: Without knowing what all those other methods do, the processing code looks fine. Are you asking how to refactor it?

Comment: Why not consolidate update/import into **upsert** action? Then, obviously, catch/log the exception when needed

Comment: Depending on the platform you are using to manage Kafka you can create a solution based on the platform itself (of course you can do it in your app as well). The idea is that you would have a "internal" processor within kafka/your app/platform to listen this 3 different events and publish it to a single aggregated topic then you consume it and do whatever you need. Confluent, Lenses are the two I know that have such capabilities there may be more out there.